# Drawing polygon on react native maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps. Is there any way to draw a polygon and get coordinates of vertices in react-native-maps?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the snippet from my code

```
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker } from "react-native-maps";


render: 

 {directions && (
            <MapView.Polyline coordinates={directions} strokeWidth={4} />
 )}
```

I am using this function to get the polyline:

```
export const getDirections = async (pickup, dropoff) => {
    let response = await callMapsAPI(pickup, dropoff)
    // console.log("Cords of direction res: ", response);
    if (response) {
        // let respJson = await response.json();
        // console.log("Cords of direction res json: ", respJson);
        let points = Polyline.decode(response.data.routes[0].overview_polyline.points);
        // console.log("Cords of direction res points: ", points);
        let coords = points.map((point, index) => {
            return {
                latitude: point[0],
                longitude: point[1]
            }
        })
        return coords
    } else return null
}
```

Where

```
import Polyline from '@mapbox/polyline';
```

Comment: I need react-native version of this http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qe68usv3/1/

Answer (score 0):

For React Native, you can use
using PanResponder to track x y and convert to latitude and longitude. You can view it here: https://github.com/dev-event/react-native-maps-draw